# C# Recursion skipping options

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm building a shifts Organizer with the use of recursion. My problem is that the recursion does not go throught every possible solution. I'm adding the code for the recursion (at least the important parts. Can someone please explain my error?

```
static bool Proccess(Point pos, User[] users, Shift shifts)
{
  if (shifts.CheckFull())
  {
    //if the solotion is better than the saved one, replace it
    return false;
  }
  Sort(users) // Sorts the users by number of shifts given to them so far (Ascending)
  if (shifts.GetShiftEmptySpace(pos) != 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
    {
        if (users[i].GetPrefs(pos) == Prefs.Natural)
           AddShift(users,pos,shifts,i);
    }
  if (shifts.GetShiftEmptySpace(pos) != 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
    {
        if (users[i].GetPrefs(pos) == Prefs.Comp_Unprefered)
           AddShift(users,pos,shifts,i);
    }
}

static void AddShift(User[] users, point pos, Shift shifts, int num)
{
  Shift shiftsTemp = new Shift();
  User userTemp = new User("");

  userTemp.CopyFromUser(users[num]);
  shiftsTemp.CopyFromShifts(shifts);

  shifts.AddShift(pos, users[num].Name, users[num].GetPref(pos));
  users[num].AddShift(pos);

  Proccess(shifts.GetNext(), users, shifts);

  users[num].CopyFromUser(userTemp);
  shifts.CopyFromShifts(shiftsTemp);
}
```

Comment: A brute-force, recursive shift organiser sounds like a pretty terrible idea. Scheduling is a highly specialised field. I'd suggest doing some reading up on algorithms before you try and write code for something like this.

Comment: Please show some sample data, what you expect and what you get. Then make your sample code a short complete recreate of your problem. As a sample your code is too much to quickly work out what you are trying to do (perhaps explaining the algorithm in prose or pseudo code would help in understanding). Summary: *make your question easier to answer*.

Comment: Well I know that recursion on it's own will not work well, I just didn't add everything I've done about it because it's not relevant to my problem. I'll explain my problem again. I need the recursion to go through all possible solutions (don't worry I filter most of the possible solutions so it won't go on forever). the problem is that I get different results with the same filters applied. this means that the recursion is not going through all possibilities. so I'm asking if someone can find a problem with my algorithm that will make the recursion draw back sooner than it supposed to.